# Отступ при использовании legend в fieldset

Tags: html, css

При использовании legend, снизу него появляется отступ и всё выглядит неравномерно:

[image]

Без использования legend всё нормально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом снести отступ снизу у legend?

```css
fieldset {border: 1px solid #cccccc; padding: 10px}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>title</legend>
  
  message
</fieldset>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ps0sL763/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`padding: 10px` , то что вам мешает. Т.к. сам `legend` занимает место:

```css
fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>title</legend>

  message
</fieldset>
```

**UPD**

```css
legend{
margin-bottom:-10px;
}
fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>title</legend>

  message
</fieldset>
```

Comment: это ведь совсем не то.

Comment: @ModaL  что не то?

Comment: Вы мне убрали верхний отступ в fieldset. Мне нужно убрать нижний отступ у legend, так как именно благодаря legend появляется ненужный мне отступ.

Comment: @ModaL можно и по другому...

Comment: такой вариант тоже был у меня. В общем как я понял нет более нормального решения, поэтому приму Ваш ответ. Спасибо :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
fieldset {border: 1px solid #cccccc; padding: 10px} 
legend {margin-bottom: -0.5em;}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>title</legend>
  
  message
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ваш ответ очень похож на ответы ваше, единственная разница - в порядке первых двух строк кода. Если порядок строк кода в данном случае важен, то добавьте информацию об этом в ответ. Если же порядок не важен, то ваш ответ - дубоикат другого ответа и его лучше удалить.

Answer (score 0):

Таким образом можно это сделать.
Ещё учёл момент, если вдруг legend будет длиннее данного ему места.

```css
fieldset {
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
legend {
  position: absolute;
  top: -13px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>titletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletletitletitletitletitletitletitletitetitle titletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletitletletitletitletitletitletitletitletit</legend>
  
  message
</fieldset>
```